# Python Popen shell=False causes OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, popen

I am trying to run the below Popen command in OSX using shell=False:

```
command = "/usr/local/itms/share/iTMSTransporter.woa/iTMSTransporter -m verify -f /Volumes/Stuff/Temp/TMP_S_0_V_TV2.itmsp -u username -p password -o /Volumes/Stuff/Temp/TMP_S_0_V_TV2.itmsp/LOGFILE.txt -s provider -v eXtreme"
self.process1 = Popen(command, shell=False, stdin=PIPE)
```

But am getting this error:

```
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is going wrong?
I also need this to function in Windows, I am aware of the directory paths, slashes, etc.

Comment: Oh if only Python could spit out what it tried to run so one could know what file or directory it couldn't find...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Popen's first argument should be a list of args. Otherwise you're telling it to find an executable named strangely.
You can use `shlex.split()` to split correctly

like `Popen(shlex.split(command), shell=False, stdin=PIPE)`

further reading: [Popen docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Comment: For windows I am changing to command = "C:\\progra~2\\itms\\iTMSTransporter -m verify -f /Volumes/Stuff/Temp/TMP_S_0_V_TV2.itmsp -u username -p password -o /Volumes/Stuff/Temp/TMP_S_0_V_TV2.itmsp/LOGFILE.txt -s provider -v eXtreme" but am now getting the error WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified not sure whats happening.

Comment: Shouldn't you change path to parameters to have windows-style slashes too? `os.path.normpath` from `os.path` might be of help. https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html